# How to write a query for hasManyThrough relations in mysql?

Tags: mysql

What is the correct way to write queries for hasManyThrough relation in Mysql?

For example, I have 5 tables. They are a, b, c, d, e. a has a hasMany relation with c through b, a also has a hasMany relation with e through d.

The schema of the example

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `c` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aId` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `cId` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_a_idx` (`aId`),
  KEY `fk_c_idx` (`cId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cId` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_aId` FOREIGN KEY (`aId`) REFERENCES `a` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `e` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `d` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aId` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `eId` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_aa_idx` (`aId`),
  KEY `fk_e_idx` (`eId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_eId` FOREIGN KEY (`eId`) REFERENCES `e` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_aaId` FOREIGN KEY (`aId`) REFERENCES `a` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT into a(id, name) values ('123', 'name');
insert into c(id, name) values ('1', 'name');
insert into c(id, name) values ('2', 'name2');
insert into c(id, name) values ('3', 'name3');
insert into b(id, aId, cId) values (1, '123', '1');
insert into b(id, aId, cId) values (2, '123', '2');
insert into b(id, aId, cId) values (3, '123', '3');
insert into e(id, name) values ('1', '1name');
insert into d(id, aId, eId) values (1, '123', '1');
```

and sqlfiddle of same

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e31b7/1

I want to use 1 query to get a row of data from a and the data is related to the row in c and e which data is connected by b and d.

Here is my try

```
select a.*,
    group_concat(lfc.id)
    group_concat(lfc.name)
    group_concat(lfe.id)
    group_concat(lfe.name)
from a,
    left join (
        select c.id, c.name, b.aId
        from b left join c on b.cId=c.id
        where b.aId=123
    ) as lfc on lfc.aId=123
    left join (
        select e.id, e.name, d.aId
        from d left join e on d.eId=e.id
        where d.aId=123
    ) as lfe on lfe.aId=123
where a.id=123 group by a.id
```

By using this query, it will cause a problem. If there are 2 rows in b, it will make the data from d has one more copy which is not what I wanted.

The data in the field group_concat(lfe.id) should contain only one data, which is the real situation in the database, rather than three. This could be done easily by using multiple queries, but I am looking for any possible way to use only one query to get the same result .

Does anyone have any idea on how to improve this query or any suggestion to write a query in the right way?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. As an aside, to my way of thinking, there is no problem in sql for which GROUP_CONCAT need form part of the solution.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: What should the desired result look like?

Comment: The data in the field group_concat(lfe.id) should contain only one data, which is the real situation in the database, rather than three. This could be done easily by using multiple queries, but I am looking for any possible way to use only one query to get the same result .

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this could work leaving the a.id in WHERE to anchor the entire query:

```
SELECT a.*,
    group_concat(c.id)
    group_concat(c.name)
    group_concat(e.id)
    group_concat(e.name)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.aId
JOIN c ON b.cId = c.id
LEFT JOIN d ON a.id = d.aId
JOIN e ON d.eId = e.id
WHERE a.id=123
GROUP BY a.id
```